# Copy large table to archive table SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with logs of my application that have 161.626.718 rows (and growing) and it's very slow to make a insert on it.
My idea is to keep only 6 months of log in the table and all older records I want to copy on a archive table that is not accessible by the application and if anyone need some info, just do a select direct on the table.
So, the idea is to create a daily job like this:

```
SELECT * INTO audlog_backup FROM audlog WHERE XDATE <= DATEADD(day,-185,GETDATE())

DELETE FROM audlog WHERE XDATE <= DATEADD(day,-185,GETDATE())
```

But because of the size of the table, this will take ages and will slow down or even lock the database for some time on the first run, after all most of the rows will be older then 6 months.

Whats the recommendation for doing it safely and faster as possible for the first time?

More information:

SQL Server 2012 Standard

Script of the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup](
    [PVKEY] [float] NULL,
    [DKEY] [varchar](14) NULL,
    [XDATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [XTIME] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [XFROM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [XTO] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DETAILS] [text] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [XUSER] [varchar](50) NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [PEOPLEKEY] [int] NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [ADDRESSKEY] [int] NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [XFILEKEY] [varchar](50) NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [XLOGNO] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [XTABLE] [varchar](50) NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audlog_backup] ADD [XFIELD] [varchar](50) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AUDLOG_backup] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [XLOGNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following Stored Procedure, scheduled via a SQL Server Agent job, to archive records on a continual basis. You don't need to worry about the initial move of "everything older than 6 months" as it will be taken care of naturally by this process since it will be able to archive records faster than you are inserting them. Of course, if you want to get a large chunk of those rows archived immediately, you can run this Stored Procedure manually (while the job is not running), and just pass in parameter values that are slightly higher for `@BatchSize` and `@SecondsToRun`.

Important Notes:

- Scheduled this to run via SQL Server Agent, probably once per hour
- Set defaults for `@BatchSize` and `@SecondsToRun` to match how fast data is coming into the table
- Create a NonClustered Index on `dbo.AudLog ([XDATE] ASC)`
- Assuming that `XLOGNO` is in the main `AudLog` table, remove the IDENTITY specification from the `XLOGNO` column here (in `AudLog_Backup`) as that value comes from the main `AudLog` table
- Change the datatype of the `DETAILS` column to be `VARCHAR(MAX)`: `text` has been deprecated since the release of SQL Server 2005 and is more difficult to work with.

Minor notes:

- Running this Stored Procedure, at least via the SQL Server Agent job if not also manually at first to get a large chuck of rows moved over, should be less work than swapping the table out, and there is no period of time when the `AudLog` table is empty.
- The Stored Procedure will simply exit if there is nothing to archive, so it doesn't hurt to run once per hour, or maybe every 2 - 3 hours (depending on how fast new rows come in).
- The Stored Procedure is throttled to exit after a certain number of seconds so that if it is causing contention on the main `AudLog` table, it will only be for short periods of time.
- The `OUTPUT` clause binds the `DELETE` from the main `AudLog` table and the `INSERT` into the `AudLog_Backup` table in a Transaction, so you don't need to worry about the process failing, or system shutting down / crashing, between those two operations.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AudLog_Archive
(
  @BatchSize INT = 2000, -- don't go above 3000 to avoid lock escalation
  @SecondsToRun INT = 180, -- run for 3 minutes
  @DaysToKeep INT = 185 -- archive rows older than 6 months
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, @SecondsToRun, GETDATE()),
        @ArchiveDate DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, @DaysToKeep * -1, GETDATE()),
        @RowsArchived INT = @BatchSize; -- initialize to be able to enter the loop


WHILE (@EndTime > GETDATE() AND @RowsArchived = @BatchSize)
BEGIN

    IF (EXISTS(
                 SELECT 1
                 FROM   dbo.AudLog al
                 WHERE  al.[XDATE] < @ArchiveDate
              )
        )
    BEGIN
        ;WITH batch AS
        (
            -- Keep this as SELECT * as it will alert you, via job failure, if
            -- you add columns to AudLog but forget to add them to AudLog_Backup
            SELECT  TOP (@BatchSize) al.*
            FROM    dbo.AudLog al
            WHERE   al.[XDATE] < @ArchiveDate
            ORDER BY al.[XDATE] ASC
        )
        DELETE b
        OUTPUT DELETED.* -- keep as * for same reason as noted above
        INTO   dbo.AudLog_Backup ([PVKEY], [DKEY], ...) -- specify all columns
        FROM   batch b

        SET @RowsArchived = @@ROWCOUNT;

        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01.000'; -- one second delay for breathing room
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        BREAK;
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Two approaches that I have seen used.

### Approach 1

Create an identical table to audlog, say audlog_new. Adjust Identity seed if necessary to be greater than the largest ID on your current audlog table.

Rename your existing table to something else (audlog_old) and then rename audlog_new to audlog.
Now you have all the time in the word to process your old data.
You should be able to copy the last 6 months of data from what is now old table to the new one. You can do it in batches.

### Approach 2

Similar to yours but do it in batches of say 10,000 records.
Use

```
SELECT MIN( ID ) AS FirstID, MAX( ID ) As LastID
FROM
    ( SELECT TOP 10000 FROM audlog WHERE XDATE <= DATEADD(day,-185,GETDATE())
    ORDER BY ID ) AS a

INSERT audlog_new
SELECT *
FROM audlog 
WHERE ID BETWEEN FirstID AND LastID

DELETE FROM audlog WHERE ID BETWEEN FirstID AND LastID
```